# Trying to create a .exe file using Pyinstaller for 2 .py files (main.py, config.py)

Tags: pyinstaller, executable, python-3.10

I am trying to generate a single exe file for my project using Pyinstaller.
I have 2 files I need incorporated into the executable called main.py & od_config.py

The 2 files sit within the same directory within the structure

```
.
└── overdraft_check
├── main.py
├── od_config.py
├── __init__.py
```

When I run the command pyinstaller --onefile main.py
The exe creates but I get the message saying the module od_config cannot be found.

I have tried several pyinstaller commands to fix the issue including the following:

`pyinstaller --onefile main.py od_config.py`

`pyinstaller --onefile main.py --hidden-import=od_config.py`

I have also tried editing the main.py file to import in different ways:
from overdraft_check import od_config as config
import od_config as config

I have also tried editing the .spec file to include the od_config.py file as part of the Analysis section:

```
    a = Analysis(
        ['overdraft_check_main.py', 'od_config.py'],
        pathex=[],
        binaries=[],
        datas=[],
        hiddenimports=[],
        hookspath=[],
        hooksconfig={},
        runtime_hooks=[],
        excludes=[],
        noarchive=False,
    )
```